# Loading pins on the map every 5 seconds is not showing the icons when i add the removeMarker function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am refreshing google maps JSON file every five seconds to get new pins, whenever i do any changes in the database and add new pins, they show up on the map, but the weird thing is when i remove the coordinates of a pin from the database the pin does not disappear from the map, rather stay there,

**here is my code**

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
});  

setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON('pins.php', function (items) {

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        (function(item) {
          addMarker(item.PinLatitude, item.PinLongitude, map);
        })(items[i]);

      }
    removeMarker();  
    });
}, 5000);
```

**here is my addMarker function**

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markers = [];

function addMarker(lat, lng, map) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(latlng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: 'iconPin.png',
    map: map
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  markers.push(marker);//this note below
  return marker;
}
```

markers.push(marker); *//when i'm adding this to save the markers in the array to be able to remove them later the map do the fit bounds as it detected the pins but no pins icons show up on the map*

**and here is my removeMarker function**

```
function removeMarker() {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();//needed to clear out the bounds
    for (i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

i tried adding an alert for the markers array in the main code in the set interval in place of the removeMarker function but the alert goes off every 5 seconds empty with nothing in the array

Comment: You need to remove the markers _before_ you add the new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the markers before you add the new ones

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON('pins.php', function (items) {

    removeMarker();  
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        (function(item) {
          addMarker(item.PinLatitude, item.PinLongitude, map);
        })(items[i]);

      }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Probably want to delete the markers array after removing them from the map also:

```
function removeMarker() {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();//needed to clear out the bounds
    for (i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
}
```

Comment: thank you my bad that works fine, but i have another question when i add map.fitBounds(bounds); after the for loop in the removeMarker function it stops working, how can i make the map fitBounds after moving a Pin ?